# Remove XML node from CXF response

Tags: java, xml, cxf

I'm looking to remove a node from a XML response I'm getting from a  web-service. I'm trying to accomplish this by using StaxTransformFeature but have been unsuccessful on being able to remove the `ns1:ivrOrderRequest0Response` node of the response.

```
    final StaxTransformFeature feature = new StaxTransformFeature();
    feature.setInDropElements(Collections.singletonList("ns1:ivrOrderRequest0Response"));
    feature.initialize(client, client.getBus());
```

**The XML I'm dealing with is:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:ivrOrderRequest0Response xmlns:ns1="http://type.webservice.net/" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <ivrOrderRequest0Return href="#id0"/>
    </ns1:ivrOrderRequest0Response>
    <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://type.ivrwebservice.net" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:IVRReturn">
      <DCRIS_RC xsi:type="xsd:string">0326</DCRIS_RC>
      <DCRIS_Return_Description xsi:type="xsd:string">NUMBER-DIRECT RECORD NOT FOUND</DCRIS_Return_Description>
      <dcrisRec1 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec10 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec2 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec3 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec4 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec5 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec6 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec7 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec8 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec9 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <telephoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">4024642151</telephoneNumber>
    </multiRef>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

**The desired result is:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
      <ivrOrderRequest0Return href="#id0"/>
    <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://type.ivrwebservice.net" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:IVRReturn">
      <DCRIS_RC xsi:type="xsd:string">0326</DCRIS_RC>
      <DCRIS_Return_Description xsi:type="xsd:string">NUMBER-DIRECT RECORD NOT FOUND</DCRIS_Return_Description>
      <dcrisRec1 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec10 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec2 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec3 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec4 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec5 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec6 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec7 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec8 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <dcrisRec9 xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
      <telephoneNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">4024642151</telephoneNumber>
    </multiRef>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If anyone has experience with this help would be greatly appreciated!